# add input and my problem in jQuery

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery, jquery-effects

Here are the problems that I'm facing with a small jQuery script :

1. In the input with value hello after I click on add button followed by clicking on remove, The link to add vanishes. What triggers this in jQuery?
2. Upon clicking on add below the second input, a new link for remove is added for each input field that is added, I would want only one remove link that would remove the most recently added input field.

Check out [My jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgDcq/) to see the problems in action.

Comment: Seconded, have absolutely no idea what you are asking.

Comment: what you not understand? see this link: http://jsfiddle.net/pgDcq/

Comment: 1.get cleaned, link add after click on remove in input hello . 2.added link remove, additional.

Comment: I don't intend to offend you, but it would really help if you worked on your english. I'm no master myself but on reading this I didn't understand a thing. Please don't take it as an insult or negative criticism. I'm sure you have great coding skills but working on your language will really make you a better developer.

Comment: Is there a need for the fourteen `div` elements? Have you considered using a couple of fieldsets for the columns?  (I'm assuming 'columns' from the name/class of some of the `div`s, anyway). I can't help but feel there's a (much) simpler way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
****** MIND READING MODE ON ******
```

I think this is what you need:

http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/pgDcq/4/

Tell me if it's ok

UPDATE

```
****** MIND READING MODE OFF******
```

Mission accomplished